# Physics Shape are not matching with Objects' shape when in contact

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have two objects and I want something to happen when they are both in contact. One object is an SCNSphere and the other one SCNCylinder. The only issue is that when I throw the ball at the cylinder, they seem to be touching even if there is a gap. If I throw it very far away then it works as expected. How can I make the contacts accurate and do lot leave any gaps? It looks like the PhysicsShape does not match my object's shape. I want it to be accurate. Any help?

My code for cylinder:

```
let scorer = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.02, height: 0.01)
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "basketballSkin.png")
scorer.materials = [material]

let scorerNode = SCNNode(geometry: scorer)

scorerNode.worldPosition = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -1.35, z: -1.4)

let physicsShapesc = SCNPhysicsShape(node: scorerNode, options:[SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron])

let physicsBodysc = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: physicsShapesc)

scorerNode.physicsBody = physicsBodysc
```

`scorerNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.scorer.rawValue
    scorerNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.scorer.rawValue |    BodyType.ball.rawValue
    scorerNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.scorer.rawValue | BodyType.ball.rawValue`

My code for ball:

```
let ball = SCNSphere(radius:0.04)
   // Bucketnode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.2,0.2,0.2);
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "basketballSkin.png")
    ball.materials = [material]

    let ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: ball)

    ballNode.position = cameraPosition

    let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: ballNode, options:nil)

    let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: physicsShape)

    ballNode.physicsBody = physicsBody


    let forceVector:Float = 2.7

    ballNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3Make(cameraPosition.x * forceVector, cameraPosition.y * forceVector, cameraPosition.z*forceVector), asImpulse: true)

    ballNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ball.rawValue
    //ballNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.ball.rawValue | BodyType.scorer.rawValue
    ballNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.ball.rawValue | BodyType.scorer.rawValue

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)

  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) { // change 2 to desired number of seconds
 ballNode.removeFromParentNode()


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking in account the definition for the SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType structure regards a geometry "Values for the type key specifying the level of detail that SceneKit uses when creating a physics shape based on a **geometry**." the option set would not probably be working as expected:

```
let physicsShapesc = SCNPhysicsShape(node: scorerNode, options:[SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron])
```

Besides that, how fast the ball is moving towards the bucket? the "concavePolyhedron" seems to be the most demanding type for rendering

Comment: How can I reduce the speed of the ball? I can't seem to find a solution. :(

Comment: I just tried changing the physics world speed, it is the same. Actually, my scorerNode is place inside a bucket, but it registers the contact even when touching the border of the bucket. That's my problem. Do you know what can cause this>

Comment: Found my solution. I had to set contact bit mask for all objects on the scene even if I do not need any contact notifications from them. :D